# The database "WSS_UsageApplication" in SQL instance on computer "" is running out of space

Tags: sharepoint-server

The database "WSS_UsageApplication" in SQL instance on computer "" is running out of space.

To fix this issue a simple increases in space on DB will work?

We had an related to below link earlier, are these two issues inter related?

> Table RequestUsage_Partition12 has 444858368 bytes that has exceeded the max bytes 444858368

[Blind spots in Usage file and Web Analytics Reports](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint_strategery/2012/04/16/blind-spots-in-usage-file-and-web-analytics-reports/)